# NExpectation not working

Tags: probability-or-statistics

If I write in Mathematica

```
NExpectation[-1 + 0.2*Z + b1 - b0*b4*a0^4*a2, {
  a0 \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[5, 4], 
  a2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-5, 20}], 
  b0 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-5, 20}], 
  b1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 2], 
  b4 \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[0.35], 
  Z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 2]}]
```

I obtain a numerical value (an expectation). This works well. However, if I change the last a2 by Z, I obtain no result:

```
NExpectation[-1 + 0.2*Z + b1 - b0*b4*a0^4*Z, {
  a0 \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[5, 4], 
  a2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-5, 20}], 
  b0 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-5, 20}], 
  b1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 2], 
  b4 \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[0.35], 
  Z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 2]}]
```

Mathematica just returns my input copied. What is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you use the option `Method`

```
NExpectation[-1 + 0.2*Z + b1 - 
  b0*b4*a0^4*Z, {a0 \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[5, 4], 
  b0 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-5, 20}], 
  b1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 2], 
  b4 \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[0.35], 
  Z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 2]},
 Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "RandomSeed" -> 0}]

(* -0.999432 *)
```

Alternatively,

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[
   -1 + 0.2*Z + b1 - b0*b4*a0^4*Z,
   {a0 \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[5, 4], 
    b0 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-5, 20}], 
    b1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 2], 
    b4 \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[0.35], 
    Z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 2]}];

Mean@dist

(* -1. *)

SeedRandom[0];
data = RandomVariate[dist, {1000}];

Mean@data

(* -0.96742 *)

Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"]
```

[image]

For both of your expectations you can use [`Expectation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expectation.html) rather than [`NExpectation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NExpectation.html)

```
Expectation[-1 + 0.2*Z + b1 - 
  b0*b4*a0^4*a2, {a0 \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[5, 4], 
  a2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-5, 20}], 
  b0 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-5, 20}], 
  b1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 2], 
  b4 \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[0.35], 
  Z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 2]}]

(* -3.78409 *)

Expectation[-1 + 0.2*Z + b1 - 
  b0*b4*a0^4*Z, {a0 \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[5, 4], 
  b0 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-5, 20}], 
  b1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 2], 
  b4 \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[0.35], 
  Z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 2]}]

(* -1. *)
```

**EDIT:** `Expectation` can handle the general symbolic case

```
Expectation[
  C[0] + C[1]*Z + C[2]*b1 - C[3]*b0*b4*a0^4*Z, 
   {a0 \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[a0α, a0β], 
   b0 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{b0min, b0max}], 
   b1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[b1μ, b1σ], 
   b4 \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[b4p], 
   Z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[Zμ, Zσ]}] // FullSimplify

(* C[0] + Zμ C[1] + b1μ C[2] - (
 a0α (1 + a0α) (2 + a0α) (3 + a0α) (b0max + 
    b0min) b4p Zμ C[3])/(
 2 (a0α + a0β) (1 + a0α + a0β) (2 + a0α + 
    a0β) (3 + a0α + a0β)) *)

% /. {C[0] -> -1, C[1] -> 1/5, C[2] -> 1, C[3] -> 1,
  a0α -> 5, a0β -> 4, b0min -> -5, b0max -> 20,
  b1μ -> 0, b1σ -> 2, b4p -> 35/100, Zμ -> 0, Zσ -> 2}

(* -1 *)
```